# The wider I make my user control, the more gets cut off on the right

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have a user control containing 2 child controls:

- A label on the left with Anchor set to Left|Right|Top|Bottom
- A picture box on the right with Anchor set to Right|Top|Bottom.

I expect the picture box to stay attached to the right side of the control, which it does in the designer. However, when I actually run my program, the picture box seems to float off the right side of the control if I make the control wider than about 100 pixels, and at 150 pixels, the picture box (which is 20x20) is completely invisible!

I don't have any code adjusting the anchor style of the picture box at runtime, so how can this be happening and how can I fix it?

Comment: Does the control need to be adjustable? How is your PictureBox aligned?

Comment: The control is adjustable so that I can display different amounts of text in the label in different spaces. For instance, I might have a large space where I want to show "50.00k (+8250)" in the label, and a small space where I only care about the "50.00k".

Comment: Picture boxes have alignment?

Comment: I think I meant anchor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, using Dock instead of Anchor seems to have solved my problem! I set the picture box to dock right, and the label to dock fill, and now it seems to look right!

Answer (score 2):

I solved this problem by setting the AutoScaleMode property in the parent control to None.

Answer (score 0):

May I suggest you to use the Anchor property, instead of the Dock property, with the same values.

Comment: Sorry, I am in fact using Anchor. I just typed Dock by mistake. I'll go back and edit my post.

Comment: Ahhh, OK... Considering other options: are the controls inside a panel? Because in that case, maybe the panel is not docked to the user control.

Answer (score 0):

I think just using Anchors instead of setting Docks may help:

If you intend PictureBox just to be attached to the right side of control - use Anchor property set to Right | Top (but it can overlay label on the left in case, when control width will be to small)

If you intend to stretch PictureBox when control is resized vertically then set Anchor = Right | Top | Bottom.

If you want PictureBox to stretch vertically and horizontally when container control resized set all Anchors (in that case label won't be overlayed by PictureBox)

Labels Anchor is better to set to just Left | Top, because anchoring it to Left | Right, may lately, in case with different TextAlign values, be causing shifts of text across the control when resizing

Comment: Sorry, I am using Anchor, not Dock; I typed Dock by mistake.

Comment: I want the picture box to stay 20x20, and the label to expand to fill the rest of the space.

Comment: Then set all label anchors and for the PictureBox set just Right and Top anchors - that may help

Comment: By the way it's better not use Dock set to fill, because in that case your PictureBox will overlay your label (or label overlay PictureBox), you may not see that now because your label now not filled with a lot of text, but it may show later